# How to convert string to long int in omnet++?

Tags: omnet++, inet

In omnet++ 5.5.1, i declared a vector in NED file using string:

```
string state = default("1 2 3 4 5");
```

In the .cc file, I wrote

```
std::vector<std::string> statesStr = cStringTokenizer(par("state")).asVector();
               std::vector<long> statesPar;
               for (auto k : statesStr) {
                   // How to convert the string to long?
                   statesPar.push_back(k.c_str()); // error
               }
```

The above code shows the below error

invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘std::vector::value_type {aka long int}’ [-fpermissive]

Would anyone please suggest to me how to fix the error? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic C++ question, unrelated to OMNeT++. You cannot put a string into a long vector. Strings can be converted to long with the `std::stol()` function.